# Converting/Reading Values from SPI Encoder to Integers

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

Im currently doing a project that includes reading values from an absolute encoder that uses SPI. Taking those values modifying them and sending them to a motor. Ive been able to read the values from the encoder however they are coming out as what I understand as 'List' Variables which I cannot modify and send back out. I need to convert these into integers. When I try

```
int(temp[1])
```

I get this error: *"TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"*
Here my code:

```
#Import Librarys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import spidev

#Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)

#Declare variables and librarys
temp = [1,2]
spi = spidev.SpiDev()

#Recieving Values from Absolute Encoder

while True:

spi.open(0,0)                       #Opens the SPI Slave State Port for communication

spi.xfer([0x10])                    #Transfers the read position command [0x10]
while spi.xfer([0x10])!=[0x10]:     #Waits for the response
    spi.xfer([0x00])                #Sends a blank command while waiting
    time.sleep(.1)

temp[0] = spi.xfer([0x00])          #Pulls first Byte
temp[1] = spi.xfer([0x00])          #Pulls second Byte



print(temp[0])
print(temp[1])
```

Here is an example of my output:

```
[10]   
[125]
[10]
[125]
[10]
[125]
[10]
[125]
[10]
[125]
[10]
[125]
[10]
[125]
```

Answer (score 0):

`spi.xfer` always returns a list. If you know you're only getting one byte back you can just retrieve it by index:

```
temp[0] = spi.xfer([0x00])[0]
temp[1] = spi.xfer([0x00])[0]
```